# Make object follow rotation with very little difference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making my object follow the rotation of another object. I want my object to rotate with very little difference, that is, from its current rotation it should not rotate completely with the other object.
There should be a difference u pto its rotation such that it should rotate 10% of what the main object rotates. How do I do this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowRotationWithLimit : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject objectToFollow;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        this.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (this.transform.eulerAngles.x, objectToFollow.transform.eulerAngles.y, this.transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

I am not able to get that logic of creating that difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather call it `FollowRotationWithFactor` then and simply use a multiplier

```
public class FollowRotationWithFactor : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject objectToFollow;
    public float factor = 0.1f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        var eulerAngles = transform.eulerAngels;
        eulerAngles.y = objectToFollow.transform.eulerAngles.y * factor;
        transform.eulerAngles = eulerAngles;
    }
}
```